# blur в expo не работает

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Нужно размытие для View элемент.
Я пробовал использовать:

1. expo blur, но это не похоже на размытие а похоже на непрозрачность.
2. @react-native-community/blur - когда я импортирую BlurView,
   я получил ошибку undefined object BlurView. У него есть решение для этой ошибки (react-native link @react-native-community/blur) но я использую expo

Comment: Нууу... в официальной доке написано, что если вы используете expo, то нужно импортировать из другого пакета: `import { BlurView } from 'expo-blur';`

Comment: Сейчас проверил официальный пример с сайта - он не работает на моем MI9. Возможно, это баг библиотеки

Comment: спасибо за попытку хотя